# How to update HTML DIV from PHP conditional

Tags: php, jquery, html, conditional-statements

I am trying to update a HTML DIV dynamically while updating some information in a MySQL database, without reloading the page. How do I get this HTML DIV to update?

```
     echo "<td id=\"trade_refs_update\">".(($results[$k]["trade_references_supplied"] == "Yes") ? "<img src=\"images/checkmark.png\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\" />" : "")."</td>";
```

Here's the PHP code:

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST["edit_app"]))
{

$columnname=$_REQUEST["column"];
$value=$_REQUEST["editval"];

if ($set_trade_references == 'Yes') {
    $sql_update=('UPDATE apps_data set `'.$columnname.'` = "'.$value.'", "trade_refs" = "Yes" WHERE app_id='.$app_id.';');
    echo "<script>$('#\"trade_refs_update\"').html('\"<img src=\"images/checkmark.png\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\" />\"');</script>";
} else {
    $sql_update=('UPDATE apps_data set `'.$columnname.'` = "'.$value.'" WHERE app_id='.$app_id.';');
    echo "<script>$('#\"trade_refs_update\"').html('\"<img src=\"images/error.png\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\" />\"');</script>";
}
$results = $db_handle->executeQuery($sql_update);
if ($DEBUG =='On'){
  echo "columnname: ".$columnname."<BR>";
    echo "value: ".$value."<BR>";
    echo "sql_update: ".$sql_update."<BR>";
}
}
```

Comment: You might do a little research into sanitizing your query, definitely don't use this code in a public facing production environment.

Comment: Please explain? What needs to be sanitized ?

Comment: You are pulling values straight out of $_REQUEST and putting them into a query. The user can supply values that may be malicious. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're searching for [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)! :)

Comment: I have tried some Ajax routines as well, but this piece of PHP code is inside a conditional and it doesn't seem to work as I expect it to.